# students’ awareness or students awareness

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I would like to write:'To increase students' awareness' but I found lots of people would write it differently, such as:

1. To increase student awareness
2. To increase students awareness
3. To increase student's awareness

I think 'To increase students' awareness' sounds better. Can anyone help me? thanks!!

Comment: Related: ["I know Bryan’s height" or "I know Bryan height"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60004/i-know-bryan-s-height-or-i-know-bryan-height) and ["the page elements" or "the page's elements"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64619/the-page-elements-or-the-pages-elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me think:

> To increase students' awareness

The apostrophe is here to mark the possessive (to show that something *has* the following object, in this case "awareness") case of the noun it goes after, in this case "students". If you are talking about the awareness of a specific group of students, there should be a definite article before "students'". See the fourth case below if you'll keep as is.

> To increase **student awareness**

This is a **noun adjunct construction**, used to mark the last noun in it as having something to do with the nouns right before it.

> To increase **students** awareness

This is just grammatically incorrect. An accompanying noun adjunct does not take the plural form, unless a singular does not exist (e.g. **clothes** line, etc.).

> To increase student's awareness

Slightly odd, but not wrong, per se. This sort of thing is usually used when referring to general concepts that are "possessed" by something. (e.g. prosecutor's immunity, fool's gold,  ...)

"Student awareness" or "the students' awareness" are best here, in my opinion.