# Is it child elements or children elements?

Tags: plural-forms

If we specify an item, and its multiple elements underneath, should we use

1. child elements, or
2. children elements

? Are they both acceptable?  And if we just use one word, then "children" is the correct word? (the parent element and its *children*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [students’ awareness or students awareness.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79814/students-awareness-or-students-awareness) Freom the answer there, [*An accompanying **noun adjunct** does not take the plural form, unless a singular does not exist (e.g. clothes line, etc.).*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/79816/126) (A "noun adjunct" is ***a noun used adjectivally***, as "child / children" in your examples.)

Comment: that one was about the apostrophe while this question is about singular / plural

Comment: The specific statement I copied above is all you needed to know here. There are *many* other ELL questions asking about essentially the same thing, but that's a good summary of the basic principle.

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase *child elements*, *child* is essentially an adjective modifying *elements*.

Adjectives in English do not change to harmonize with the plurality or any other aspect of nouns as done in other languages.  So it would remain *child*.

> And if we just use one word, then "children" is the correct word? (the parent element and its children).

Yes, in this case, since you're using *child* as a noun and not an adjective/modifier, you'd change it for plurality.

Comment: then it is even harder verbally: sometimes we may say "the element and its children" and feel it is better to add the word "elements" to it, and we have already said "children" -- cannot backspace to say child.

Comment: There's nothing "hard" or "unusual" about referring to an [***element** and its **child elements***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22element+and+its+child+elements%22) in English.

Comment: @nopole Lol. Don't get married to the beginning of a sentence if it dooms the rest of it. There's nothing wrong with *the element and its children* (in the right context), however.

Comment: @userr2684291: As a programmer, I'm *really* familiar with both those forms *(child elements / children),* so nothing "jars". I can't really say the same about ***daughters*** for ***daughter cells*** in the biology context though (it's just a bit too "inappropriately anthropomorphic" for me). And [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cell+and+its+daughter+cells%2Ccell+and+its+daughters&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccell%20and%20its%20daughter%20cells%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccell%20and%20its%20daughters%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree.